# Trying to move to Jetty from Tomcat for testing on workstation, tomcat vs jetty

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, maven, jetty

I been programming Spring/Web projects for sometime using eclipse and tomcat but now that I am getting into Maven I am also thinking about using jetty for my workstation testing.

I made a sample web app and if I run it on tomcat from eclipse I goto **http://localhost:8080/TestJetty/** but if I do a mvn jetty:run I have to access it from **http://localhost:8080/**

Why is that?

Also can I setup eclipse to run jetty?  whats the pros and cons of both

Answer (score 1):

Normally with "jetty:run" goal of maven jetty plugin the context path is `/`, unless it is overridden with a contextPath configuration entry:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>Your version..</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/mycontextpath</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

From within Eclipse probably it is your project name that is being used as the context path.

Regarding pros and cons, it simply is your level of comfort, I prefer command line and so would normally run it outside of eclipse using "mvn jetty:run"

Comment: I tried adding your conf for the contextPath but it did not work

Comment: Yes, without any issues - are you seeing any issues with Spring projects and jetty:run?

Comment: Not sure, it could be because of the plugin version - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin. This works for me perfectly